# Leetcode solution not working the same as local environment (Surrounded Regions)

Tags: java, algorithm

https://leetcode.com/problems/surrounded-regions/

I read through the editorial, and coded up a solution. Everything makes sense, and locally my code changes the board to the expected output, yet when I paste the code to Leetcode, my board stays the same. I used their debugger and placed a breakpoint at line 24, sure enough, I don't see any changes on the board.

Not sure where else to ask this, so I'm sorry if this isn't the right place.

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
  private int ROWS;
  private int COLS;

  public void solve(char[][] board) {
    ROWS = board.length;
    COLS = board[0].length;

    // parse left and right borders
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      DFS(board, i, 0); // left border
      DFS(board, i, ROWS - 1); // right border
    }

    // parse top and bottom borders
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      DFS(board, 0, j); // top border
      DFS(board, COLS - 1, j); // bottom border
    }

    // after parsing, we end up with x, o, e board. Pass through it, and change 
    // 1) o to x
    // 2) e to o
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 'o') {
          board[i][j] = 'x';
        }
        else if (board[i][j] == 'e') {
          board[i][j] = 'o';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void DFS(char[][] board, int i, int j) {
    if (i >= ROWS || j >= COLS) return; // bounds
    if (board[i][j] != 'o') return;

    board[i][j] = 'e'; // temporary marker, to help identify border-connected cells
    // go right
    DFS(board, i, j + 1);
    // go down
    DFS(board, i + 1, j);
    // go left
    DFS(board, i, j - 1);
    // go up
    DFS(board, i - 1, j);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    char[][] test1 = new char[][] {
      {'x','x','x','x'},
      {'x','o','o','x'},
      {'x','x','o','x'},
      {'x','o','x','x'}
    };

    new Solution().solve(test1);
    Arrays.stream(test1).forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
  }
}
```

Running it locally, I get exactly what's expected in the console

[x, x, x, x]

[x, x, x, x]

[x, x, x, x]

[x, o, x, x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that your code assumes a matrix of *lowercase* O and X, while the LeetCode problem gives you matrix of *uppercase* O and X. Since `'o'` is not the same as `'O'`, and `'x'` is not the same as `'X'`, your code doesn't solve the LeetCode problem.

In the future, I recommend using copy-and-paste when copying test-cases, so that you get them exactly right.

---

Since I'm here, I'll also point out two other issues with your code:

- Your depth-first search has logic to ensure that you never walk off the bottom or right edge of the grid, but it doesn't do anything to ensure that you never walk off the top or left edge. (Your test-case doesn't trigger that, because there are no O's along the top or left edge that test-case.)
- Your code has various comments that talk about "parsing", when in fact you're doing no such thing. (See https://www.google.com/search?q=parsing.) That won't affect your code's behavior, obviously, but it can confuse human readers, or at least make you look a bit clueless. I'd suggest writing (for example) `// find all O's connected to left and right borders, and change them to E's`.

Comment: Much appreciated. I always thought that "parse" just meant "go through" so thank you for pointing that out.